# difference between {str} and {str_} in Python

Tags: python, string

I am trying to debug a code in Python. When I go to debug mode and look at the variable `word` in a similar code that works fine, I see the type of this variable is shown as `{str}`, but in the other code that does not work correctly I see the type of `word` in the debugger is shown as `{str_}`.
What is the difference between these and how can I convert a variable type `{str_}` to a type `{str}`.

Here is part of the code:

```
cv = CountVectorizer(min_df=1, charset_error="ignore", stop_words="english", max_features=200)
counts = cv.fit_transform([text]).toarray().ravel()
words = np.array(cv.get_feature_names())
...
for word, count in zip(words, counts):
```

I use PyCharm to debug, and it is in Python 3.3.

I appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Please, post the code snippet that you are having problems with and which debugger you are using.

Comment: What Python version is this?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I use PyCharm to run the code and debug.

Comment: @user2357112 it is Python 3.3

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`str` is probably the builtin `str`. `str_` is something else. Perhaps a subclass of `str`? Hard to tell without seeing more

Edit:

Looks like `str_` may be `numpy.str_` which is what you'll get if you pour a list of str into a numpy array

Comment: Thanks for the help. What type of more info should I provide?

Comment: First paste the actual output from the debugger

Comment: `word={str_}علمی` is the output of the debugger. What is shown after {str_} is a Farsi word (in UTF8) format.

Comment: Is there a way I convert `str_` to `str`?

Comment: Just pass it to `str()`?

Comment: Actually passing it to str() changed `str_` to `str`, so the fact that the string is not shown as expected is related to something else.